# Fast matrix multiplication loop for C=AA'B

Tags: fortran, matrix-multiplication, blas

The task is to do an operation *C=AA'B*, where *A, B* and *C* are rectangular arrays. This can be achieved via BLAS by sequence of gemm calls using an intermediate matrix *T*, eg. *T=A'B* and *C=AT'*. I am wondering whether there is a "smarter" way of doing this since *AA'B* can be reformulated as a sequence of outer vector products. So a bare loop in Fortran looks like this:

```
    allocate(xxx(size(A,1)),source=0.0)
    Do i=1,size(B,2)
      !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(tmp) FIRSTPRIVATE(xxx) REDUCTION(+:C)
      xxx=0.0
      !$OMP DO
      Do j=1,size(A,2)
        tmp=0.0D0;
        Do k=1,size(A,1)
          tmp=tmp+A(k,j)*B(k,i)
        End Do
        if(j==1) Then
          Do k=1,size(A,1)
            xxx(k)=tmp*A(k,j)
          end Do
        Else
          Do k=1,size(A,1)
            xxx(k)=xxx(k)+tmp*A(k,j)
          end Do
        End if
      End Do
      !$OMP END DO
      C(:,i)=C(:,i)+xxx
      !$OMP END PARALLEL
    end Do
```

Is this the optimal layout in terms of memory access pattern?? And if so, how to thread it with OpenMP.
All my threading attempts were about 15 times slower than have two sequential gemm operations via MKL. So I guess I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: Bed time so not a long answer, but there's much more to it than just walking down memory in the right order, see e.g. https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/cache-blocking-techniques for starters. And once you have read that and related material decide that it's best left as an SEP and use BLAS.

Comment: You can refer to section 6 "what programmer can do" of https://people.freebsd.org/~lstewart/articles/cpumemory.pdf The paper named "What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory", a long paper.

Comment: You would really have to show your threading attempts and first comoare them with your serial code and only then with MKL. Also, first compare serial with serial, then threaded with threaded.

Comment: And if I may adding my 2 cents. Most modern CPUs profit heavily from vectorisation command sets like AVX2 on amd64 architectures. Without them, you are already depending on floating point precision anywhere between 2 (long double precision) to 8 (single precision) times slower. Memory prefetching adds to that, so the differences that you obtain make perfect sense to me. One last consideration regarding complex matrices: The multiplication of multiple complex floats profits oftentimes again a factor of 2.

Comment: Added the omp threading. Since B can be anything down to one column but A will generally have a lot of columns, I decided to thread the first inner loop.